# How to concatenate associated row names in R?

Tags: r

I'm new in R and I want to do simple operations on the columns of my file. Would someone help me to do this?

I have two big files A and B. There is a specific pattern in columnI@II of my file A. I want to capture it and transform it to the second column of file B. Basically for every name in column I of file A, there are different names in the second column of it. So I want to write the all associated names for every name in the first column into the file B

Here is the structure of my files and desired output:

File A :

```
 family               ID    
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7a  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7b  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7c  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7d  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7e  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-let-7f  
let-7/98/4458/4500      hsa-miR-98  
miR-1ab/206/613         hsa-miR-1   
miR-1ab/206/613         hsa-miR-206 
.
.
.
```

Output for file A :

output A :

```
miR family                  ID
let-7/98/4458/4500       hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7/hsa-miR-98
miR-1ab/206/613          hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
.
.
.
```

File B:

```
let-7/98/4458/4500
let-7/98/4458/4500
miR-1ab/206/613             
miR-1ab/206/613
miR-1ab/206/613             
miR-1ab/206/613
.

.
```

Desired output for file B:

```
let-7/98/4458/4500     hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7/hsa-miR-98
let-7/98/4458/4500     hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7/hsa-miR-98
miR-1ab/206/613        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
miR-1ab/206/613        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
miR-1ab/206/613        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206    
miR-1ab/206/613        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
.
.
```

Comment: First use `aggregate` on file A, and then `merge` it with file B.

Answer (score 1):

A demonstration of my comment:

```
out <- merge(aggregate(ID ~ family, A, paste, collapse="/"), B)
out
#               family
# 1 let-7/98/4458/4500
# 2 let-7/98/4458/4500
# 3    miR-1ab/206/613
# 4    miR-1ab/206/613
# 5    miR-1ab/206/613
# 6    miR-1ab/206/613
#                                                                             ID
# 1 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98
# 2 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98
# 3                                                        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
# 4                                                        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
# 5                                                        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
# 6                                                        hsa-miR-1/hsa-miR-206
```

This is given the following sample data for "A" and "B":

```
A <- structure(
  list(family = c("let-7/98/4458/4500","let-7/98/4458/4500","let-7/98/4458/4500",
                  "let-7/98/4458/4500","let-7/98/4458/4500","let-7/98/4458/4500",
                  "let-7/98/4458/4500","miR-1ab/206/613","miR-1ab/206/613"),
       ID = c("hsa-let-7a","hsa-let-7b","hsa-let-7c","hsa-let-7d","hsa-let-7e",
              "hsa-let-7f", "hsa-miR-98", "hsa-miR-1","hsa-miR-206")),
       .Names = c("family", "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

B <- structure(
  list(family = c("let-7/98/4458/4500","let-7/98/4458/4500","miR-1ab/206/613",
                  "miR-1ab/206/613","miR-1ab/206/613", "miR-1ab/206/613")),
  .Names = "family", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```